# Serving ads only for users who didn't buy application

Tags: ios, iad

I'm switching my iOS app from priced to free and adding ads instead. The issue is, some people already brought the app, and it would seem like a rip off if they start getting ads with the update. Is there a way I can check whether someone has already brought the app, and make it so that ads aren't delivered to them?

Comment: Yeah, this didn't come up while i was searching around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do this. You can't  recognize point in time when user bought the app.

You can release (still paid) version that would record the fact the user has bought it somehow - either by marking it in defaults or sending device ID to your server. But this doesn't cover 100% cases. When old user completely deleted and install app again - or install the app on the new device - you will still serve them ads.

Comment: is there anyway i can get the device IDs of people who already brought my application without having to issue a new update? From say, something like itunes connect?

Comment: No. iTunes will not give you such information. You need to write something and deploy it as an update.

Comment: Under iOS 7, this is possible. See the duplicate I referenced above.

Answer (score -2):

When you submit your new app, add a test with the version of your App. 
Remove the ads for users who have a version less than the new one.

You can use this code to find the build version :

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Comment: So when user who bought the app before will upgrade - you will show him the ads?

Comment: I supposed the ads are coming with an update. So it's work.

Comment: @JordanMontel I don't really follow. Wouldn't this test have to be in the updated app? So if anybody already with the app updated, the version number will be different, and the ads will be served anyway.

Comment: It's work for an update. But yes, it's not going to work if the user download the app from another device or delete and download again the app.

Comment: But the update will have the newer version, wouldn't it?

Comment: The update will have a new version number. And all new features you want.

Comment: And will show ads. Which defeats the purpose

Comment: Not for an update. For a new download OK but for an update it's good.

Comment: No it's not. New install or update your code will return same value.

Comment: Let's say the ads will be in version 1.1. This test will only come in version 1.1 So when anybody updates the app, it will check the version, which will be a 1.1. This will serve ads. If the version is still 1.0, the piece of code wouldn't even be there, and there will be no ads, but no update either, which defeats the whole point.

Comment: Yep, so, for an user who paid the version 1.0 and update to 1.1 it's work. But, if the user paid the version 1.0, delete the app (or install the app with the same account on another device) and install the version 1.1, he will have the ads.

Comment: @sha it's work for an update. You need to add a test with the new version compare to the previous BECAUSE you know the number of the previous version.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that for some reason, the app version will not be updated with the app update. Even if you buy version 1.0, the version will change to 1.1 after the update.

Comment: @malfunction: exactly!!

Comment: @JordanMontel How do you know the number of the previous version? Once the update is installed, you can't determine what the previous version was unless the previous version saved that information in NSUserDefaults or some other location. An update can't even tell it was an update unless there is some saved data that can be looked for.

Comment: Ok I was wrong. Hum.. Add an update to keep in User Default the current value of the previous version and It will be work ahah :p

Comment: @JordanMontel But it's too late for that. The OP would need to release an update that saves the old version then release the new version that uses ads. But this won't work in many cases because not every user will upgrade to the intermediate version. And all of this only works when a user updates. It doesn't work when a user installs on a new device or deletes and reinstalls. See the duplicate I referenced above for a proper solution under iOS 7.